# How to receive a mail whenever a file gets deleted?

Tags: scripting, ksh

I've accidentally deleted my `cron` using `crontab -` command and now the file under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory got deleted.

I would love to have a script which mails whenever my files under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` got deleted. I'm using `ksh` shell.

Comment: You can write script to achieve this and you have to make a habit to use that script when ever you need to delete a file.

Comment: Thanks ramp!!. I've sorted out by using a simple command [ -f /var/spool/cron/crontabs ] || echo "/var/spool/cron/crontabs  missing"  >> file_list.changes and then using the file_list.changes file to mail. This simple script by using nohup helps me finding whenever the directory/file goes missing.

Comment: I'm not sure why being told you've just lost your `crontab` file is of much use. Stable doors, and all that. So, my personal take on this is that I maintain `~/.crontab` as my `crontab` file, and then submit that whenever I change it with `crontab ~/.crontab`. This won't avoid accidental deletion, but it does make it harder to lose.

Answer (score 1):

If you have inotify tools, then

```
dir=/var/spool/cron/crontabs
inotifywait --monitor --event delete -r "$dir"
```

will get you a line whenever a file in `$dir` gets deleted.
You can pipe that to your mailer or a loop that runs your mailer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate but is there any workaround other than using inotify tools. Really appreciate for the help.

Comment: As far as I know, the only alternative to using the inotify system is polling.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a configuration management system like *puppet* or *chef* that will periodically check the system and enforce the proper content for critical files (like crontab).

Such systems can also be setup in audit mode only, so you will just receive an alert when a file changes.

This may be overkill for just a couple of personal system files.

Alternatively, only populate your crontab from a master file that you store in *git* or some other source code repository.